# Mach-O Linker reference error, but can't find the source file

Tags: ios, cordova, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to add facebook connect login to my phonegap/cordova app using the https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect plugin.

When I go to build the app, I get an error

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in FacebookConnect.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FacebookConnect)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker caommand failed with exit code 1 (user -v to see invocation)
```

I've been going through my files, and don't have any file called `FacebookConnet.o`, just `FacebookConnect.h` and `FacebookConnect.m` in my plugins directory, and a `Facebook.h` within the `FacebookSDK.framework`.

```
-Plugins
   FacebookConnect.h
   FacebookConnect.m
   -FacebookSDK.framework
       -headers
          Facebook.h
          FacebookSDK.h
          etc, etc, etc
```

Is the `.o` file created during the build, and if so, hwo can I find where this error might be so I can try to fix it? 
Or any other suggestions on resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Facebook.h, show Utilities (right tab), and click on File Inspector.

Is your project in Target Membership checked? If not, make sure it's checked and try again.

Comment: When I view Facebook.h, it doesn't have the option of Target Membership. However, the FacewbookSDK.framework does have that option. When I enable Target Membership, I go from 2 errors to 24 though. sqlite3 errors and then facebook errors continue. Maybe that's right, I'm not sure, but i normally feel like less errors is better than more.

Comment: oops sorry. I meant Facebook.m. Can you try to enable Target Membership in Facebook.m.

Comment: There isn't a Facebook.m, just a FacebookConnect.m which already has the target membership checked. I removed the plugin and added it again, and the FacebookSDK.framework had target membership already required, so I'm back to the 24 errors. Mostly related to sqlite.

Comment: looks like the problem was that I didn't link in the sqlite3 library in my build settings, and add social, adnetwork and accounts libraries.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've accepted your question @yeesterbunny because your initial "Target Membership" check is what was causing the initial problem, and once that was done, I needed to make the other changes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help :)